# Can't populate when referencing a SubDocument in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a database with three relevant models, here are the mongoose schemas

```
// models/company.js
let companySchema = new Schema({
    rut         : String,
    name        : String,
    owner       : { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref : 'User'  }
})
export default mongoose.model('Company', companySchema)

// models/account.js
let accountSchema = new Schema({
    code      : String,
    name      : String,
    type      : {
        id    : Number,
        name  : String
    }
})
// I have two different exports, because sometimes I just need the schema,
// and others I need the model
export default accountSchema
export const Account = mongoose.model('Account', accountSchema)

// models/mayor.js
let mayorSchema = new Schema({
    account     : { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref : 'Account' },
    company     : { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref : 'Company' },
    month       : Number,
    year        : Number,
    data        : [{
        date    : Date,
        detail  : String            
    }]
})
export default mongoose.model('Mayor', mayorSchema)
```

I want to query my `Mayor` model from `mayorSchema`, my query is like this

```
import {Account} from '../models/account'
import Company from '../models/company'
import Mayor from '../models/mayor'

Mayor
    .find({ 'company' : companyId, 'month' : month, 'year' : year })
    .populate('company')
    .populate('account')
    .exec((err, mayores) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(err))
        res.status(500)
        res.json({
          code: "001",
          message: "Some error with the server. Please try later"
        })
      } else {
        res.status(200)
        res.json(mayores)
      }
    })
```

The result of that query is an array, but every object in the array has the `account` property set to `null`. I don't know why is that happening, if I query the data directly on mongo console, all is fine, all the documents has correctly set their account property. Some things that might be useful to know:

- I'm using express.js, part of the notation is from express.
- My account property is correctly populated
- The account schema is a subdocument (embedded) in another model, but the (account) model is correctly registered in mongoose.
- The documents in mayors collection where previously inserted with `Mayor.insertMany` method, and after that insert, if I inspect the just created documents, they have the account field correctly set.

So why is this happening? why can't I populate my `account` field. I guess that it is something related to referencing on sub documents, but I would have expected that a failed population would return just an `ObjectId`, not null.

Comment: Do you mean your company property is correctly populated ? Can you post how you define (something like `mongoose.model('MyModel' ,mySchema)` ?

Comment: Ok, I will add more info, for now notice that each model is in a single file, and I'm generally exporting the model. Generally, because in the account model I export the schema and the model, I'll show it now

Comment: I just added the import/export statement that I use. As you can see, there are difference in the account export, but I don't think is related

Comment: Try exporting Account like this : `export default mongoose.model('Account', accountSchema)`. You can access schema from model anyway (search in the model object, it is something like `mongoose.model('Account').schema`) so you don't need to export it

Comment: I tried something like exporting the account model, in the way you say and use `Account.schema` whene I need the schema, but I got some errors so  I change it to what I have now. I guess that the problem is that there is no collection called `accounts` in my database, because I removed the statement to populate the property and the result didn't change at all, so it is not related to the population, it's just getting null on accounts always

Comment: Yes you need an `accounts` collection in your db

Comment: So, is imposible in mongoose to query the reference of a subdocument? even if it allows to save it and mongodb has no problem with it?

Comment: No, you need a real collection for populate to work. I you want to keep your current schemas as they are, you will need to query the subdocument by hand. I suggest you revise the schema that contains `Account` as a subdocument, create an `Account` collection and make references to this collection in your other schemas.